# Height property css breaking parent element and cannot be contained

Tags: css, height

Okay I have this html

```
<div id="div1">
    <p id = "a">
       <! -- content -->
    </p>

    <p id='b'>
       <! -- content -->
    </p>
</div>
```

And this css:

```
div#div1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

paragraph "a" breaks parent div boundaries and runs into paragraph "b" as if "floated". Same thing happens when I set the height of the paragraph element to 200px.

How come? I just like to know. Thanks much!

Comment: is there any style associated with those paragraphs?

Comment: @SujitAgarwal no style. i noticed the same thing at w3c school tutorial and wondered why the paragraph content overflowed and invaded the paragraph below. i guess the height property is really not meant for <p> elements and only good for tables, imgs, and making sure wrapper divs blanket the browser (when html & body elements are set to height @100%, i think). thanks for the speedy reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the height of the paragraph, the paragraph will really have that height. The only problem is that the paragraph's content may not fit into the paragraph and overflow, as illstrated by this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/22uk19hf/

You can control what happens to overflowing content via the [`overflow` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> visible
>   : Default value. Content is not clipped, it may be rendered outside the content box.
>
> hidden
>   : The content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.
>
> scroll
>   : The content is clipped and desktop browsers use scrollbars, whether or not any content is clipped. This avoids any problem with scrollbars appearing and disappearing in a dynamic environment. Printers may print overflowing content.
>
> auto
>   : Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers like Firefox provide scrollbars if content overflows.